# Buscando locais próximos com DISTINCT? (Maps API)

Tags: mysql, sql, api, maps

Tenho uma tabela separada no MYSQL com os endereços dos usuários contendo as informações do local (latitude e longitude), podendo cada usuário possuir mais de um endereço cadastrado. Meu objetivo é que ao realizar uma busca por algum local, seja listado todos o usuários mais próximos desse local.

O problema é que não consigo fazer o `DISTINCT` para que cada usuário seja listado apenas uma única vez no `SELECT`. Pesquisei mais afundo e vi que o `GROUP BY` poderia resolver o problema. Ele de fato agrupa os usuários impedindo a repetição, porém ele não mantém a ordem correta que seria de menor distância.

Esse caso pode ser visto facilmente na documentação do Maps porém não é feito o DISTINCT.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Resultado sem `GROUP BY` (É o que preciso, porém sem repetir os usuários):

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
   2         1        MARIA         5
   3         2        KEVIN         6
   1         1        MARIA         8
   4         2        KEVIN         10
```

Resultado com `GROUP BY`:

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
    1         1        MARIA         8
    3         2        KEVIN         6
```

Quando na verdade teria que ser assim ...

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
   2         1        MARIA         5
   3         2        KEVIN         6
```

Com `GROUP BY`, a ordenação pela distância parece estar sendo ignorada e está aparentemente sendo feita pelo `PLACE_ID`.

Meu `SELECT` é esse:

```
SELECT place_id, id_user,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-30.053831) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-51.191810) )
 + sin( radians(-30.053831) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM enderecos
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING distancia < 25
ORDER BY distancia ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema em seu código é que você possui mais de um endereço para cada usuário. Na verdade isto não chega a ser um problema, e sim parte da aplicação.

Uma solução possível ao seu problema é continuar executando sua consulta e remover os registros duplicados posteriormente. Uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizando uma tabela temporária:

```
/* PRIMEIRO CALCULAMOS A DISTANCIA DE CADA USUARIO */
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_distancia`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_distancia` (
  place_id INT NOT NULL,
  id_user INT NOT NULL,
  distancia INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_user, distancia)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO tmp_distancia (place_id, id_user, distancia)
SELECT place_id, id_user,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-30.053831) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-51.191810) )
 + sin( radians(-30.053831) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM enderecos
HAVING distancia < 25;

/* AGORA BUSCAMOS A DISTANCIA MINIMA INDIVIDUALMENTE */
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_distancia_minima`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_distancia_minima`(
  id_user INT NOT NULL,
  distancia INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_user, distancia)
)ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO tmp_distancia_minima (id_user, distancia)
SELECT
  id_user,
  MIN(distancia)
FROM tmp_distancia
GROUP BY id_user;

/* FAZEMOS A BUSCA FINAL, ELIMINANDO RESULTADOS DUPLICADOS */
SELECT
  A.id_user,
  A.place_id,
  A.distancia
FROM tmp_distancia AS A
INNER JOIN tmp_distancia_minima AS B
  ON (A.id_user = B.id_user AND A.distancia = B.distancia)
ORDER BY A.distancia;
```

**Importante**: Na consulta acima estou assumindo que a distancia sempre será um valor inteiro. Caso não seja, mude o tipo de dados de acordo.